# Conditional cast always succeed in swift dict

Tags: swift, dictionary

Hello I have a little problem.
I am triying to build a swift dictionnary that will later be translated to json for a network code.

A simpliflied version of the code is here :

```
let result: [String: AnyHashable] = [:]
var someInt = 0
result["key1"] = [
            "A" : someInt,
            "obj": [
                "obj1": "a string",
                "obj2": "otherString"
            ]
        ] as? [String: AnyHashable]
```

using the as? [String: AnyHashable] leads to a compiler warning sayiing that casting String to String always succeed. removing it leads to a compiler error with illegal instruction.

Comment: Why does your values need to be AnyHashable instead of Any?

Answer (score 0):

Hum writing my question lead to me finding the answer.

turns out:

```
let result: [String: AnyHashable] = [:]
 result["key1"] = [...] as? [String: AnyHashable]
```

casts the right side of the equality that only need to be casted as? AnyHashable for my result array to work.

Comment: good question. In that case I need it to be Codable in fact... The reason is that this dictionary will be send in JSON format to a Backoffice and since out BO teams did not provide a clear and final json, i cannot make it a codable struct model yet